# Why doesn't my pod respond to requests on the exposed port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, sinatra, kubernetes, coreos

I've just launched a fairly basic cluster based on the CoreOS kube-aws scripts.

https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-aws.html

I've activated the registry add-on, and I have it correctly proxying to my local box so I can push images to the cluster on localhost:5000. I also have the proxy pod correctly loaded on each node so that localhost:5000 will also pull images from that registry.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/registry

Then I dockerized a fairly simple Sinatra app to run on my cluster and pushed it to the registry. I also prepared a ReplicationController definition and Service definition to run the app. The images pulled and started no problem, I can use `kubectl` to get the startup logs from each pod that belongs to the replication group.

My problem is that when I `curl` the public ELB endpoint for my service, it just hangs.

Things I've tried:

- I got the public IP for one of the nodes running my pod and attempted to `curl` it at the NodePort described in the service description, same thing.
- I SSH'd into that node and attempted `curl localhost:3000`, same result.
- Also SSH'd into that node, I attempted to `curl <pod-ip>:3000`, same result.
- `ps` shows the Puma process running and listening on port 3000.
- `docker ps` on the node shows that the app container is not forwarding any ports to the host. Is that maybe the problem?

The requests must be routing correctly because hitting those IPs at any other port results in a `connection refused` rather than hanging.

The Dockerfile for my app is fairly straightforward:

```
FROM ruby:2.2.4-onbuild
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
  libpq-dev \
  postgresql-client

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ['ruby', '/app/bin/entrypoint.rb']
```

Where `entrypoint.rb` will start a Puma server listening on port 3000.

My replication group is defined like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: web-controller
  namespace: app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: secrets
        secret:
          secretName: secrets
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: localhost:5000/app:v2
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        env:
        - name: DATABASE_NAME
          value: app_production
        - name: DATABASE_URL
          value: postgresql://some.postgres.aws.com:5432
        - name: ENV
          value: production
        - name: REDIS_URL
          value: redis://some.redis.aws.com:6379
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets
          mountPath: "/etc/secrets"
          readOnly: true
        command: ['/app/bin/entrypoint.rb', 'web']
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
```

And here is my service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: web
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Output of `kubectl describe service web-service`:

```
Name:           web-service
Namespace:      app
Labels:         <none>
Selector:       app=web
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:         10.3.0.204
LoadBalancer Ingress:   some.elb.aws.com
Port:           <unnamed>   80/TCP
NodePort:       <unnamed>   32062/TCP
Endpoints:      10.2.47.3:3000,10.2.73.3:3000
Session Affinity:   None
No events.
```

`docker ps` on one of the nodes shows that the app container is not forwarding any ports to the host. Is that maybe the problem?

**Edit to add entrypoint.rb and Procfile**

entrypoint.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

db_user_file = '/etc/secrets/database_user'
db_password_file = '/etc/secrets/database_password'

ENV['DATABASE_USER'] = File.read(db_user_file) if File.exists?(db_user_file)
ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = File.read(db_password_file) if File.exists?(db_password_file)

exec("bundle exec foreman start #{ARGV[0]}")
```

Procfile:

```
web: PORT=3000 bundle exec puma
message_worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q messages -c 1 -r ./config/environment.rb
email_worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q emails -c 1 -r
```

Comment: What does `entrypoint.rb` look like (and any other files involved in starting your Sinatra app)? This could be to do with Sinatra apps in development mode only listening to `localhost` by default, but I don’t know how that interacts with Docker and the other technologies involved here.

Comment: @matt: I added the entrypoint.rb and Procfile. I don't think that would be the problem, though because running `ps aux` I can see the Puma process listening on `0.0.0.0`:
`root      1798  0.0  0.6 156236 23872 ?        Sl   00:01   0:00 puma 2.9.0 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000)`

Comment: I think you’re right. The issue I’m thinking of applies to Sinatra’s built in server, but you are starting Puma directly, so it must be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with my Kubernetes set up. It turns out that the app was failing to start because the connection to the DB was timing out due to some unrelated networking issue.

For anyone curious: don't launch anything external to Kubernetes in the 10.x.x.x IP range (e.g. RDS, Elasticache, etc). Long story short, Kubernetes currently has an IPTables masquerade rule hardcoded that messes up communication with anything in that range that isn't part of the cluster. See the details [here](http://ben.straub.cc/2015/08/19/kubernetes-aws-vpc-peering/).

What I ended up doing was creating a separate VPC for my data stores on a different IP range and peering it with my Kubernetes VPC.